# Bloomberg and updating formula if holidays give N/A

Tags: vba, excel, bloomberg

We use the BDH function to get closing prices at the end of each trading day, and do this for a list of different types of securities and indices at once.

Currently every BDH-of-index in the list refers to the same date at the top of the sheet, and if one index gives `N/A` because there is no trading on that day, we manually make it refer to a cell with another date.

```
=BDH($B4&" index","px_last",$I$1,$I$1)
```

Where `B4` refers to an index ("SPX" etc.) and `I1` = yesterday's date.

I've just written a VBA routine that updates the dates at the top, but now I want it to also check if any of the indices gives an `N/A` and, if so, let that one refer to another cell date automatically.

Can someone give me some advice on how to check the values in a row ranging c4:c20, and then change the cell that formula uses. Or should I alter the formula itself as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could probably use an override instead:

```
=BDH($B4&" index","px_last",$I$1,$I$1,"Days=A,Fill=P")
```

That will retrieve the last available price as of yesterday's close, which may be the day before yesterday's close (or an earlier date) if that specific instrument did not trade yesterday.

Comment: That works, awesome, thanks. But what do those commands actually do/mean?

Comment: Go to that cell and click on the little arrow near AutoSum on the HOME menu then More Functions. Click on the "Help on this function" link at the bottom of the window and it will open a help window with all the arguments that you can provide to BDH. Days=A means "retrieve [A]ll days, including week-ends" and Fill=P means "if you don't have data on a given day, fill with [P]revious available data".